# Internal manipulation of complex hermitian matrix / explain the use of "RealHermSymComplexHerm" in symmetric.jl

Tags: julia, lapack

I think Julia handles matrices with complex elements correctly.

My task is to modify the spectrum of a Hermitian matrix H and return just the matrix with modified spectrum. i.e. I have a function `f(real_vec)->real_vec` that modifies the spectrum `s(H)` of a hermitian `matrix H=U[s(H)]U'`. I need the result `f(H) = U[f(s(H))]U'`. I think it is possible to optimize by not computing explicitly the `eigfact(H)`.

Therefore I tried to write my own `eigmodif` based on the Julia realization of `eigfact`. That was difficult because I was lost on the line 4816 in lapack.jl, where `syevr()` is wrapped up.

I need to understand where and how, Julia has converted a COMPLEX HERMITIAN matrix to a REAL-SYMMETRIC one. Theoretically it is possible, since we have a 2n by 2n matrix J that squares to minus identity; for any n by n COMPLEX HERMITIAN matrix H we then turn it into `real(H).I + imag(H).J`, or in a block form

```
[ real(H) -imag(H) ]
[ imag(H) real(H) ]
```

But how does Julia do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert on LAPACK, but perhaps the use of macros in the definition of the eigensolvers is unclear. From `linalg/lapack.jl` (around line 4900):

```
# Hermitian eigensolvers
for (syev, syevr, sygvd, elty, relty) in
    ((:zheev_,:zheevr_,:zhegvd_,:Complex128,:Float64),
     (:cheev_,:cheevr_,:chegvd_,:Complex64,:Float32))
    @eval begin
        # SUBROUTINE ZHEEV( JOBZ, UPLO, N, A, LDA, W, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, INFO )
        # *     .. Scalar Arguments ..
        #       CHARACTER          JOBZ, UPLO
⋮  
⋮
```

So the macro code uses `$syevr` as a placeholder to refer to `:zheevr_` and `:cheevr_` in the two passes through the loop, defining the same `syevr!` for different type signatures. These are LAPACK functions dedicated to Hermitian matrices and accept complex inputs. So the meat of the calculation and complex number handling goes on inside LAPACK.